# 'Manager' object has no attribute 'create_user' in django 1.7

Tags: python, django

Hi i am taking user's username and password in django 1.7 but i am getting error - 'Manager' object has no attribute 'create_user'

my views.py

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid(): 
            post = request.POST
            username = post['username']
            email = post['email']
            password = post['password']
            user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
            return redirect('/student/lastpage')
    else:
        form = UserForm()
    return render(request, 'student/register.html', {'form': form})
```

my models.py

```
class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50)

def __str__(self):
    return self.username

class UserForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
```

any help is appreciated

thanks in advance

Answer (score 8):

Default `ModelManager` doesn't have the `create_user` method.  Set the proper manager to your `User` class. Also you need to inherit from [AbstractBaseUser](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractBaseUser) class instead of `models.Model`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, UserManager

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    ...
    objects =  UserManager()
```

Comment: but now it is giving another error-AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'UserManager'...what to do now..??

Comment: i tried it but it gave the same error..- objects =  models.UserManager()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'UserManager'

Comment: Remove `models.` from this line.

Comment: it worked but now there is another error - typeerror- 'is_active' is an invalid keyword argument for this function...now what should i do..??..and why there is this error ..i have not used is_active anywhere..

Comment: `is_active` is user in the `create_user` method. It is also used in user logging process.  You should inherit your `User` model from `AbstractBaseUser`.